# error reading protobuf spec. validator error: The. mlmodel supplied is of version 3, intended for a newer version of xcode

Tags: python, xcode, coreml, turi

I'm running this out-of-the-box turi python code:

```
import turicreate as tc
# Load the data
data =  tc.SFrame('annotations.sframe')

# Make a train-test split
train_data, test_data = data.random_split(0.8)

# Create a model
model = tc.object_detector.create(train_data, model="darknet-yolo", max_iterations=1, verbose=True)

# Save predictions to an SArray
predictions = model.predict(test_data)

# Evaluate the model and save the results into a dictionary
metrics = model.evaluate(test_data)

# Save the model for later use in Turi Create
model.save('mymodel.model')

# Export for use in Core ML
model.export_coreml('MyCustomObjectDetector.mlmodel')
```

But on the last line I'm getting the error:
model.export_coreml('MyCustomObjectDetector.mlmodel')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/amir/anaconda/envs/CowsVision/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/toolkits/object_detector/object_detector.py", line 1477, in export_coreml
    mlmodel = coremltools.models.MLModel(model)
  File "/Users/amir/anaconda/envs/CowsVision/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.__proxy__ = _get_proxy_from_spec(filename)
  File "/Users/amir/anaconda/envs/CowsVision/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py", line 103, in _get_proxy_from_spec
    return _MLModelProxy(filename)
RuntimeError: Error compiling model: "Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: The .mlmodel supplied is of version 3, intended for a newer version of Xcode. This version of Xcode supports model version 2 or earlier.".
>>>
```

In the console.

Does that mean that my local installed xcode version needs upgrade?
Where is the .mlmodel version being determined? What's "this version of Xcode"?

Comment: I reinstalled to the latest Xcode 10 beta, and the problems persists.

Comment: Note that you're using beta software. The first releases of Xcode after WWDC are usually a little behind what they actually show at the conference, and they start to become usable at beta 2 or 3. Have patience. :-)

Comment: I was getting the same error also when I was on earlier, more stable version of Xcode.

Comment: As far as I know, object detection isn't supported by the current (iOS 11) version of Core ML, even though Turi Create lets you build such models.

Comment: They have a whole example on the developer site about exporting the model to coreml so I'm not sure what do you mean.

Comment: I meant that Core ML in iOS 11 cannot do object detection models, at least not without a lot of help (it does not do any of the post-processing such as NMS). The mlmodel that the current _beta_ version of Turi Create writes is of version 3 of the spec. It looks like the current Xcode beta cannot read mlmodel version 3 files yet, only version 2 (as of iOS 11.2) and 1 (as of iOS 11.0).

Comment: oh! Is there a way to use an earlier version of Turi create then?

Comment: You could check out the branch `release_4.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments above, I've downgraded to turicreate 4.0 version and the problem was solved for me. It looks like the most recent beta version (5.1) isn't working well.